# What happens if I call the 3 ball in one corner and the 8 ball in another?

Tags: rules, pool

My last ball on the table is the 3.

I call the 3 ball in one corner and the 8 ball in the other corner. I make contact with the 3 ball first, then the 8 ball. Does it matter if the 3 ball goes in or not? Assuming the 8 ball goes in.

Was this a legal call to begin with?